# Enqueue script globally

Tags: plugin-development, customization, wp-admin, login, wp-enqueue-script

This only works for admin dashboard.

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts',array($this, 'login_register96_adminscripts'));
```

And this only works for the user place.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this , 'login_register96_scripts') );
```

Is there a way I can enqueue a script globally?
Which will be operational on the whole website including admin dashboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any other way but to use both add_action lines, for a single function.

Example:

```
function my_enqueue_sripts_function_name(){
    
    // your enqueue logic here
    
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',    'my_enqueue_sripts_function_name' );
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_sripts_function_name' );
```

There's no rule that forbids you from adding the same function on multiple hooks.

Furthermore, if you need to know which action called the function, from within the function, you can use `current_action()` or `current_filter()`